# How do I load JSON objects into separate global variables using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I have one JSON file with data that I want to load into separate variables. 
My JSON file has two objects/arrays: "views" and "addressbook". I can bind the data to a $scope.variabale in the html but but that's not what i'm looking for. I would like to load the views and addressbook into a "var views" and a "var adressbook" so i can access them with jquery.

My JSON:

```
{
    "myData": {
        "views": [
            {
                "view": "Nieuwe activiteit",
                "link": "index.html",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "view": "Activiteiten",
                "link": "activiteiten.html",
                "active": false
            }
        ],"adresboek": [
            {
                "Voornaam": "Ruben",
                "e-mail": "ruben@e-mail.com",
                "mobiel": "0612345678",
                "hasFacebook": true,
                "hasTwitter": true
            },
            {
                "Voornaam": "Roos",
                "e-mail": "roos@e-mail.com",
                "mobiel": "0612345677",
                "hasFacebook": true,
                "hasTwitter": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to get:

```
var alldata = $http.get('data/data.json').then(function(res) {
    var views = res.data.mydata.views;
    var adresbook = res.data.mydata.adresbook;
 });
```

I would like to bind the data like so:
$scope.views = alldata.views;
$scope.contacts = alldata.addressbook;

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can reference the global scope with window.  window.alldata = ...

Answer (score 0):

You can access the JavaScript global scope at any point by referencing the window object.  Make sure to use $apply in angular if you modify data outside off the angular digest.  In your example:

```
var alldata = $http.get('data/data.json').then(function(res) {
    window.alldata = {
       "views": res.data.mydata.views,
       "addressbook": res.data.mydata.adresbook
    };
 });
```

You may now access the data in jQuery, e.g.:

```
console.log( window.alldata.views );
```

Comment: Tnx Scott. Tried this, didn't work. i get "undefined" for console.log(window.alldata) and console.log(windows.alldata).

Comment: try `console.log(window.views)` and `console.log(window.adresbook)`

Comment: @Chennard - I modified my original answer to reflect your desire to have views and addressbook within an alldata object.  Overall, it's still the exact same answer - but now the wrapped within alldata.   You can access by using alldata, or window.alldata from within your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you want to put these variables on the global scope/window?  This is typically advised against.  You may consider creating an Angular Service.  A Service allows you to access variables across different modules.

In the context of your code, where is this $http.get request occurring?

**EDIT:  In response to your comment:**

Ok, try something like this?

```
myApp.controller( 'getData', function($http){  
  this.onLoad: function(){  
    $http.get('data/data.json').then(function(res) {  
      $scope.views = allData.views;  
      $scope.contacts = allData.addressBook;  
    }  
  };  
  this.onLoad();  
};
```

When you're first instantiating your angular controller it will call the loadData function and set your $scope variables.

(I didn't check your $http code, I just copied what you had down).

Comment: I'm prototyping and not concerned with security. The request is occuring at the verry beginning, it's the only javascript i have.
var myApp = angular.modelll
myApp.controller...$http
var alldata..

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, let me know if that is more helpful to you.

Comment: @ChadF What if I do not want my service to fetch the json everytime someone asks for this data? How can I fetch once?

Comment: If you put your HTTP logic in a service (where it should be) you could memoize your function or set the result as a service property and then check if that property is defined. i.e., stick `if (this.data) { return this.data }` before the http request